# Convert character to numeric in xts object

Tags: r, xts

My desire is to convert to numeric all numbers in the following xts object.

Morover, if it was possible, substitute NA with the previous number in the same column

```
library(xts)
x <- structure(c("1176.67", "1175.37", "1196.10", "1182.90", "1200.30", 
"1183.20", "170.0674", "170.0586", NA, "170.1376", "170.1651", 
"170.1844", "252.10", "252.07", "252.07", "252.23", "252.34", 
"252.40", "616.09", "618.49", "620.44", "624.61", "626.66", "627.92", 
"1.44730", "1.44430", NA, "1.43710", "1.44730", "1.44120", "5238.815", 
"5238.458", "5256.423", "5261.352", "5235.514", "5182.277", "5669.918", 
"5673.797", "5668.293", "5677.272", "5613.539", "5608.027", "399.106", 
"398.800", "399.411", "402.521", "400.797", "401.521"), class = c("xts", 
"zoo"), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tclass = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "GMT", tzone = "GMT", index = structure(c(1419292800, 
1419379200, 1419552000, 1419811200, 1419897600, 1419984000),
tzone = "GMT", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), .Dim = c(6L, 8L),
.Dimnames = list(NULL, c("GC1 COMDTY", "IBOXXMJA", "LT01TRUU",
"LT11TRUU", "MEDLCCU", "NDDLUS", "NDDUE15", "NDUEEGF")))
```

Answer (score 11):

You can set the `storage.mode` to numeric.

```
storage.mode(x) <- "numeric"
```

But I encourage you to look for the root cause/source of your data being cast as character in the first place. Setting the `storage.mode` to numeric is potentially destructive if some of the values in your object can't be represented as numeric (R will throw a warning if any value cannot be converted).

After converting to numeric, you can use `na.locf` to fill in the missing values with the previous value.

```
x <- na.locf(x)
```

Comment: Perhaps it is worth mentioning that `na.locf` is from the `zoo` package?

Comment: @DMC: Why? If you're using xts, zoo must be loaded (xts depends on zoo).  And if you call `na.locf` on an xts object, `na.locf.xts` is dispatched.

Comment: While the OP probably had zoo loaded, as a reproducer of the problem it's perfectly possible to have an object of class zoo in memory but not have the zoo package loaded. Trying to reproduce the problem, I got `Error: could not find function "na.locf"'

Comment: @DMC: then the problem is that you need to load xts, which will also load zoo. I'll edit the OP.

Comment: thank you, storage.mode works ok for me. It's also possible to use as.numeric for core data and after rebuild the xts object.

Comment: This transforms character variables into NAs

Answer (score 0):

You can try this：

```
x1 <- apply(x,2,as.numeric)
```